# Divs will not float properly in Nested Grid system

Tags: html, css

I am using a 16 grid system. Two 8 columns divs (floating side by side). Within the 8 column div I want to have a 5 column div to the left and two three columns divs to the right stacked on top of each other. I have tried everything I can think of and find and nothing seems to work. The grid system I am using is Skeleton. Here is the HTML & CSS as it stands right now. Ive tried floating the 5 column grid to the left and the other two to the right. I've tried clear fixes. Please help!

```
<div class="container">
<article id="main">
<div class="eight columns">
      <section class="five columns bulletin alpha">
        <h2>Bulletin Board</h2>
          <p>Post 1</p>
      </section>
      <div class="clear"></div>
      <aside class="three columns take5 omega">
       <ul>
        <li><h3>Take 5</h3></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/75x75" alt="Learning Break icon"  /></a></li>
                <li><h3>Learning Break</h3></li>
              </ul>
        </aside>
      <aside class="three columns longTerm omega">
      <ul>
      <li><h3>Long Term</h3></li>
      <li><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/75x75" alt="Long Term Learning icon" /></a></li>
      <li><h3>Learning</h3></li>
      </ul>
     </aside>
</div>

The CSS looks like this:
.bulletin {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
width: 100%;
float: left;
    }
.take5, .longTerm {
margin: 0;
width: 100%;
padding: 0;
float: right;
    }
```

Comment: Am I missing something? 5 + 3 + 3 = 11. How do you expect to end up with 8 columns?

Comment: So how can I do what I am trying to accomplish.? I would attach a picture of my design but I don't see a way to insert a picture. I need it to be a larger Div within the eight column gird and then two smaller divs next to it stacked on top of each other.

Comment: Also even when I remove the second 3 column div I still cant get the five column and three column to float next to each other

Answer (score 0):

The reason your containers won't float next to each other is because you've given each a width of 100%. This forces the containers to fill up all the horizontal space inside the parent container they exist within. That means the next div will be pushed down below it and they wind up stacking.

Remove the `width: 100%` in your CSS, or preferably set a finite width, and they'll float next to each other.

Note: You still have a math problem where you want 8 "columns" but are creating 11. Maybe that's just a problem with your semantics, since you'll clearly wind up with 11 columns given what you've put in your markup, but it's something you should sort out because it's obviously confusing.

http://jsfiddle.net/40wwjL5q/

Comment: I removed the third three column div so I just have the 5 column and the 3 column div. I removed the 100% width and it didn't work,, the did not float. I then added a width of 200px on the 5 column one and 100 on the 3 column one, well under what it should hold side by side and still they don't float.

Comment: I posted a link to a working example. It's your code above with the width properties removed from your CSS. Are you sure you're using the same markup that you posted?

Comment: Thanks. I ended up switching grid systems to Zen grids. It works great and looks great in everything but IE. In IE it pushes all the DIVS in the grid off to the left hand side. Any idea what might be causing that or how to fix it?

Comment: You should post that as a separate question with examples of your markup.

Comment: Thank you. I did and got an answer that worked. I added respond.js and modernizer.js and it all works in IE now.